# Angular 2 Accessing AWS API Gateway

Tags: angular, cors, aws-api-gateway

Baffled on what the issue is here.  I am trying to access a Lambda function on AWS through my Angular 2 application.  Cross origin is enabled in AWS.  In Chrome I am getting 200 responses in the Network tab.

Preflight Options Request
[image: Preflight Options Request]

GET Request
[image]

The console however shows a 403
[image]

Here is the Angular code

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

getAWS(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('https://9rw0xrw730.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/...', {
        headers: {
        'x-api-key': 'myapi key'
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: The response headers for the GET request show that there’s no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response. That is, the server is sending the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header only for the response to the preflight OPTIONS request. It needs to be configured to also send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header for GET responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved...

I had to explicitly add it to the Lambda Function itself.  I did add it to the API Gateway which got me to the point above.  But still didn't have the header on the actual response.

Here is the Lambda code:
[image]